# how to declare two arrays in json?

Tags: json, json.net

I want to create a json string for my web application. Actually i am new to this json format.In my json string i have to create two arrays in my json structure.But i have some syntax problem in creating two arrays. my json string is given below for your reference.

```
{
    MarkUpdate:[
        {
            'FinalMarks':[
            {
                'studentId':'S1',
                'Ques_Mark':[
                {
                    'qId' :'Q1',
                    'mark':'14',                
                },
                {
                    'qId':'Q2',
                    'mark':'10',                
                }
                ]
            },          
            {
                'studentId':'S2',
                'Ques_Mark':[
                {
                    'qId' :'Q1',
                    'mark':'12',                
                },
                {
                    'qId':'Q2',
                    'mark':'13',                
                }               
                ]
            }
            ]
        }           
        ]
    }
```

In my above json string format,my `MarkUpdate` contains one array object named as `FinalMarks`.So,here i have to create one more array object named as `EvalMarks` under `MarkUpdate`.

Acually my `EvalMarks` contains following elements...

```
'EvalMarks':[
            {
                'EvalId':'E1',
                'Ques_Mark':[
                {
                    'qId'   :'Q1',
                    'studId':'S1',  
                    'mark':'13',                
                },
                {
                    'qId':'Q2',
                    'studId':'S1',  
                    'mark':'13',                                    
                }                   
                ]
            },

            {
                'EvalId':'E2',
                'Ques_Mark':[
                {
                    'qId'   :'Q1',
                    'studId':'S2',  
                    'mark':'10',                
                },
                {
                    'qId':'Q2',
                    'studId':'S2',  
                    'mark':'10',                                    
                }
                ]
            }
            ]
```

So, i have declare this `EvalMarks` under the `MarkUpdate`.I missed the syntax...

Could you plz tell me how to add this array object under the `MarkUpdate`.

guide me to get out of this issue...

Comment: ["stash", 2, "json", { "objects": ["in", "here"] }, "seperated by commas", ["except", "for", "the last entry"]];  Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To declare two arrays in one JSON object, remember that the JSON object can only be a single object, therefore the array must be inside the enclosing curly braces. For example:

```
{
  "array1":[1,2,3],
  "array2":["jim","louise","mark"]
}
```

For your case, it's important to remember that you should properly indent your braces, square and curly, so that you can visually identify mistakes before they become problems. I stringly recommend http://jslint.com/ to validate your JSON before using it. It's also great for Javascript:

```
{
    "MarkUpdate":[
        {
            "FinalMarks":[
                {
                    "studentId":"S1",
                    "Ques_Mark":[
                        {
                            "qId" :"Q1",
                            "mark":"14"
                        },
                        {
                            "qId":"Q2",
                            "mark":"10"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "studentId":"S2",
                    "Ques_Mark":[
                        {
                            "qId" :"Q1",
                            "mark":"12"
                        },
                        {
                            "qId":"Q2",
                            "mark":"13"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "EvalMarks":[
        {
            "EvalId":"E1",
            "Ques_Mark":[
                {
                    "qId"   :"Q1",
                    "studId":"S1",
                    "mark":"13"
                },
                {
                    "qId":"Q2",
                    "studId":"S1",
                    "mark":"13"
                }
            ]
        },

        {
            "EvalId":"E2",
            "Ques_Mark":[
                {
                    "qId"   :"Q1",
                    "studId":"S2",
                    "mark":"10"
                },
                {
                    "qId":"Q2",
                    "studId":"S2",
                    "mark":"10"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not a valid JSON if you have commas after the last key-value pair in an object. I would start by knocking off all those unnecessary commas after the last key-value pairs inside most of your objects and validating the JSON in www.jslint.com

To be more clear ,

```
{
    "qId":"Q2",
    "studId":"S2",  
    "mark":"10",                                    
}
```

is Not Valid. 
On the other hand,

```
{
    "qId":"Q2",
    "studId":"S2",  
    "mark":"10"                                   
}
```

Is valid.