# How to send multiple JSON objects as a stream using alamofire

Tags: json, xcode, alamofire, swift4

I want to send multiple different JSON object in a single request, i felt streaming the multiple JSON objects like a file in a single request would be better, so kindly let me know if it is possible, if so kindly give me an idea of how to do it using Alamofire, Below is the formate of the raw body (application/json) data that i want to post

```
{"a":23214,"b":54674,"c":"aa12234","d":4634}
{"a":32214,"b":324674,"c":"as344234","d":23434}
{"a":567214,"b":89674,"c":"sdf54234","d"34634}
```

I tried the below code, but it didn't work as the body param is not in the correct format, that's the reason i want to try sending the multiple JSON objects as a stream in a single request, Kindly advice

```
let SendParams = [
      ["a":1234, "b":2345, "c":3456], ["a":2345, "b":3456, "c":4567], ["a":3456, "b":4567, "c":5678]
    ]
_ = Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding, headers: header)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722669/how-to-declare-two-arrays-in-json

Comment: The format he is using has a key on the top level json object, where as here it doesn't have a key. That's the reason i am stuck.

Comment: @ThooyavanManivaasakar since JSON objects constructed with key,value paris you must have a key to pass the value.

Comment: I have changed my question as this was what i meant to ask and got confused on my way, kindly try to check out and help me out.

Comment: check out [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29910166/post-multiple-json-objects-in-alamofire-post-method-swift-ios/52854143#52854143)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[JSON](https://www.json.org/) format is not correct for your request, JSON is always key-value pair, where key is always `String`, and value is any `Object`. In your example need to set key at top level for object of type `Array` as below:

```
let SendParams = [
                    "key" :[["a":1234, "b":2345, "c":3456], ["a":2345, "b":3456, "c":4567], ["a":3456, "b":4567, "c":5678]]
                ]
_ = Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: SendParams, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) in}
```

OR

Serialise the array and set as `httpBody` of `URLRequest` object:

```
    let url = YOUR_POST_API_URL
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    let values = [
        ["a":1234, "b":2345, "c":3456], ["a":2345, "b":3456, "c":4567], ["a":3456, "b":4567, "c":5678]
    ]
    request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: values)

    Alamofire.request(request)
        .responseJSON { response in
            // do whatever you want here
            switch response.result {
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)

                if let data = response.data, let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                    print(responseString)
                }
            case .success(let responseObject):
                print(responseObject)
            }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, i need to send it as multiple JSON objects, not as nested JSON object. So kindly help me in sending multiple JSON objects in body of a Alamofire request or as a stream of multiple JSON Object.

Comment: @ThooyavanManivaasakar check the updated answer for jsonserialization body request with array.

Comment: Hi, Thanks will try using it and update you on the result. Thank you.