# Alamofire send Array of Dictionaries in a parameter

Tags: ios, alamofire, swift4

I have a `POST API` in which I send multiple parameters, one of those parameters has to be an `array` of `dictionaries`.

```
let arr = [
    [
        "id" : "1",
        "price" : "10"
    ],
    [
        "id" : "2",
        "price" : "20"
    ]
]
let params : Parameters = [

    "param1" : "anyvalue1",

    "param2" : "anyvalue2",

    "param3" : arr,

    ]
```

When I use these parameters in `Alamofire Request` and hit the API, `print(res.result.value)` always returns unknown. Can anyone help me with this. Following is the way of requesting the API

`Alamofire.request(url, method:.post, parameters: params).responseJSON{(res) in
          print(res.result.value) //always shows 'unknown' as output 
        }`

Comment: [You can use like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48495353/how-to-send-multiple-json-objects-as-a-stream-using-alamofire/48537265#48537265)

Comment: Have you inspected the request, to see if your data is sent with the request?

Comment: THank you @Rocky , worked like a charm. had to add `encoding: JSONEncoding.default`

Answer (score 0):

Try to make params a Dic of [String :Any ] like that :

```
let params : [String:Any] = [

    "param1" : "anyvalue1",

    "param2" : "anyvalue2",

    "param3" : arr,

    ]
```

Comment: Alamofire's Parameters type is a typealias for [String:Any], so this really doesn't change anything

Comment: got the problem solved. had to use `encoding: JSONEncoding.default`

Comment: Alamofire uses defualt **encoding: JSONEncoding.default** there's no need to set in request