# Send Parameters in Below format by using Alamofire

Tags: ios, json, swift, parameter-passing, alamofire

I am Alamofire for API calling in my project and I want to make parameters in below format for "language" key :

```
[
  {
    "isSelected": true,
    "languageProficiencies": [
      {
        "isSelected": false,
        "name": "Advance"
      },
      {
        "isSelected": true,
        "name": "Proficient"
      },
      {
        "isSelected": false,
        "name": "Basic"
      },
      {
        "isSelected": false,
        "name": "Below Basic"
      }
    ],
    "name": "English"
  },
  {
    "isSelected": false,
    "languageProficiencies": [
      {
        "isSelected": false,
        "name": "Advance"
      },
      {
        "isSelected": false,
        "name": "Proficient"
      },
      {
        "isSelected": false,
        "name": "Basic"
      },
      {
        "isSelected": false,
        "name": "Below Basic"
      }
    ],
    "name": "Malay"
  },
  {
    "isSelected": false,
    "languageProficiencies": [
      {
        "isSelected": false,
        "name": "Advance"
      },
      {
        "isSelected": false,
        "name": "Proficient"
      },
      {
        "isSelected": false,
        "name": "Basic"
      },
      {
        "isSelected": false,
        "name": "Below Basic"
      }
    ],
    "name": "Mandarin"
  },
  {
    "isSelected": false,
    "languageProficiencies": [
      {
        "isSelected": false,
        "name": "Advance"
      },
      {
        "isSelected": false,
        "name": "Proficient"
      },
      {
        "isSelected": false,
        "name": "Basic"
      },
      {
        "isSelected": false,
        "name": "Below Basic"
      }
    ],
    "name": "Tamil"
  }
]
```

Currently my format for "language" key is:

```
["resource": ["language": [["languageProficiencies": [["name": "Advance", "isSelected": true], ["name": "Proficient", "isSelected": false], ["name": "Basic", "isSelected": false], ["name": "Below Basic", "isSelected": false]], "isSelected": "true", "name": "English"], ["languageProficiencies": [["name": "Advance", "isSelected": false], ["name": "Proficient", "isSelected": false], ["name": "Basic", "isSelected": false], ["name": "Below Basic", "isSelected": false]], "isSelected": "false", "name": "Malay"], ["languageProficiencies": [["name": "Advance", "isSelected": false], ["name": "Proficient", "isSelected": false], ["name": "Basic", "isSelected": false], ["name": "Below Basic", "isSelected": false]], "isSelected": "false", "name": "Mandarin"], ["languageProficiencies": [["name": "Advance", "isSelected": false], ["name": "Proficient", "isSelected": false], ["name": "Basic", "isSelected": false], ["name": "Below Basic", "isSelected": false]], "isSelected": "false", "name": "Tamil"]], "user_id": 384]]
```

Please provide me suggestions to do same format as I mentioned first. Thanks in advance!! Happy coding!!

Comment: how are you making your current format ? Show that code please.

Comment: @Sachin you can do it like [this answaer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48495353/how-to-send-multiple-json-objects-as-a-stream-using-alamofire/48537265#48537265)

Comment: @Sachin is your second JSON in proper format, I am getting error while formatting

Comment: @anoop4real second is my parameter dictionary that I have passed in Alamofire parameter of type "Parameters"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array contains the object of dictionary and languageProficiencies is also an array and its also contains the object of dictionary.

You can archive this type of format using below code :

```
var mainArray:[[String: Any]] = []
for i in 0...1 {
    var dict:[String: Any] = [:]
    dict["isSelected"] = "true"
    dict["name"] = "English"

    var arrLanguageProficiencies:[[String: Any]] = []
    for j in 0...1 {
        var dictLangProf:[String: Any] = [:]
        dictLangProf["isSelected"] = "false"
        dictLangProf["name"] = "Advance"
        arrLanguageProficiencies.append(dictLangProf)
    }
    dict["languageProficiencies"] = arrLanguageProficiencies

    mainArray.append(dict)
}

do {
    let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: mainArray, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)
    let theJSONText = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.ascii.rawValue)!
    print ("JSON Text :"+(theJSONText as String))

} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)
}
```

And Output looks like :

```
[
    {
        "name" : "English",
        "isSelected" : "true",
        "languageProficiencies" : [
            {
                "name" : "Advance",
                "isSelected" : "false"
            },
            {
                "name" : "Advance",
                "isSelected" : "false"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name" : "English",
        "isSelected" : "true",
        "languageProficiencies" : [
            {
                "name" : "Advance",
                "isSelected" : "false"
            },
            {
            "name" : "Advance",
            "isSelected" : "false"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```