# How to post an array of dictionary (json object), in swift using alamofire?

Tags: ios, swift3, httprequest, alamofire

How I need to post the request:
[image: How I need to post the request]

How it looks in the database:
[image: how it looks in the database]

Hello, I am working on a food app, I need to send the order details to the database. To do that, I have created a data type like

```
class orderModel : NSObject {

var menu_name : String = ""

var quantity : Int = 0

var price : Double = 0.0

var menu_id : String = ""

init?(menu_name : String,menu_id : String, price : Double,  quantity : Int) {

    guard !menu_id.isEmpty else{
        return nil
    }

    self.menu_name = menu_name
    self.menu_id = menu_id
    self.price = price
    self.quantity = quantity

  }

}
```

this. I'm then placing the order with,

```
 let parameters : Parameters = [
                    "custid" : defaults.object(forKey: "userid")!,
                    "carttotal" : Int(totalPrice),
                    "cartitems" : ordersArray,
                    "deliverytime" : timeSlot,
                    "custaddress" : custAdd!,
                    "areacode" : defaults.object(forKey: "areaCode")!
                ]

    Alamofire.request(orderPlaceURL, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { response in

        print((response.result.value)!)

    }
    totalPrice = 0.0
    ordersArray.removeAll()
```

The posted data should look like the first image, but when it's entered into the database, it shows like the second image. Instead of the array elements, just the word "Array". Can anyone please suggest me what to do?

Comment: use `JSONSerialization` to add your array in form of parameter

Comment: okay.. completely forgot to serialise the json data..

Comment: @K.Mitra Check out this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48495353/how-to-send-multiple-json-objects-as-a-stream-using-alamofire/48537265#48537265

Comment: thanks.. I used Codable to get a string value from my modeled data and then passed the string in the post parameter.. thanks for the suggestions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Alamofile` Parameters object is of type `[String: Any]`, which is not what you want. 
Instead make an array of multiple dictionaries and pass that to this function :

```
func uploadDataToServer(endPoint: String, dataToUpload: [[String: Any]], completionHandler:@escaping (Bool) -> ()){

    let url = Config.BASE_URL + endPoint

    var request = URLRequest(url: URL.init(string: url)!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    let dataToSync = dataToUpload
    request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dataToSync)

    Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON{ (response) in

        print("Success: \(response)")
        switch response.result{
        case .success:
            let statusCode: Int = (response.response?.statusCode)!
            switch statusCode{
            case 200:
                completionHandler(true)
                break
            default:
                completionHandler(false)
                break
            }
            break
        case .failure:
            completionHandler(false)
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Your array should be :

```
var uploadArray = [[String: Any]]()
let ordersDictionary = [
                    "custid" : defaults.object(forKey: "userid")!,
                    "carttotal" : Int(totalPrice),
                    "cartitems" : ordersArray,
                    "deliverytime" : timeSlot,
                    "custaddress" : custAdd!,
                    "areacode" : defaults.object(forKey: "areaCode")!
                ]

uploadArray.append(ordersDictionary)
```

Then pass `uploadArray` to above function.