# post array of json with alamofire swift

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, alamofire

How can i post array of json objects with alamofire in swift?

my final data *(which i want to post)* looks like:

```
temp = [{
        "time": 1,
        "score": 20,
        "status": true,
        "answer": 456
    },
    {
        "time": 0,
        "score": 0,
        "status": false,
        "answer": 234
    },
    {
        "time": 0,
        "score": 20,
        "status": true,
        "answer": 123
    }
]
```

i got hint that i have to create custom parameter encoding but i am confused how can i do that. Someone please help me.

```
my current code looks like
let parameters: Parameters = [
    "answers": temp,
    "challenge_date": "2019-03-01"
]

Alamofire.request("...url", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
    .responseJSON {
        response in

            if
        let status = response.response ? .statusCode {
            let classFinal: JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)

            if (status > 199 && status < 300) {
                self.dismiss(animated: true)
            } else {


            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: I guess temp is your array. Any errors that you are facing with this?

Comment: you need to send temp in the format of array & dict. See carefully, treat `[ ... ]` as array and `{ ... }` as dict. Now set **answers** value with this. **NOTE** Your post req params data is always be in array and dict not json.

Comment: @GaneshSomani "JSON parse error - No JSON object could be decoded"

Comment: How is your `Parameters` class implemented. That is the source of your error.

Comment: Please see the edited question. This is my final case.

Comment: @DeepakVerma check out this may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48537265/1042817

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code change method **.put** to  **.post**, and not required to `SVProgressHUD.dismiss()` in else, because you already dismiss before if else part

Also, you need to convert your JSON string(temp variable) to array and then pass with the parameter.

```
let parameters: Parameters = [
            "answers": temp,
            "challenge_date": "2019-03-01"
        ]

    Alamofire.request("...url", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding:  JSONEncoding.default , headers: headers)
        .responseJSON { response in

            if let status = response.response?.statusCode {
            let classFinal : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)
                SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                if status > 199 && status < 300 {                    
                     self.dismiss(animated: true)
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: yes. still getting error "JSON parse error - No JSON object could be decoded"

Comment: temp is your JSON string right?, So you need to convert JSON to the dictionary and then pass with the parameter

Comment: first, check your request and parameter with the postman, is it working fine?

Answer (score 0):

I hope your `Parameters` class follows `Codable` protocol.

As far as I see, you are getting an error parsing that object to JSON. Hence that is the source of your error.

Could you also add code for your `Parameters` class / struct

Answer (score 0):

First, convert your Temp

***Array into String***

than pass in that in parameters of Alamofire.

```
extension NSArray {
    
    func toJSonString(data : NSArray) -> String {
        
        var jsonString = "";
        
        do {
            
            let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data, options: .prettyPrinted)
            jsonString = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)! as String
            
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        
        return jsonString;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: temp is an array of json not a dictionary

Comment: Now pass your Array and get String.

Answer (score 0):

This is for **Swift 5**  . Please make sure encoding must be  **encoding: JSONEncoding.default** . temp can be simple **string Array** or **dictionary** **array**. This work for me .

```
let url = ""
    print(url)
let temp: [String] = ["",""]
  let parameters: Parameters = [
"answers": temp,
"challenge_date": "2019-03-01"]
    
    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    ]
    print(params)
    AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
        .responseJSON(completionHandler: { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
            print("Success")
           case .failure(let error):
                print(error)  }
        })
```