# How to post JSON with Array of Dictionaries : Alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire, swifty-json

i want to post array of dictionaries in alamofire, but some how it is not posting.i can use many ways but still not find the proper answer on it. Showing error "Extra argument 'method' in call" . Here is my code.

```
let userToken: HTTPHeaders = [
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    ]
let parm = [
            [
                 "EmployeeID": id,
                 "Longitude":  longitude,
                 "Latitude":   latitude,
                 "GeoTime":    dateString,
                 "UserToken":  "g98XQdy8B}rQ7?Q"
            ]
          ]
postAttandance(apiUrl: postAttandanceURL, parameter: parm , tiket: userToken){
        (done) -> Void in
        if done{

        }
    }

func postAttandance(apiUrl : String , parameter : [[String : Any]] ,  tiket : HTTPHeaders , completion : @escaping (_ done : Bool) -> Void ){
    Alamofire.request(apiUrl, method : .post , parameters : parameter ,encoding : JSONEncoding.default,  headers : tiket).responseJSON { (response) in
        if response.result.isSuccess{
            let responsejson : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)
            completion(true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `parameter` parameter of `Alamofire.request` function is typealias `Parameter`, which is `[String : Any]`, what you are passing to it is `[[String : Any]]`. As `Alamofire.request` function comes with default parameter values, any invalid parameter type assigned to the function will give you the error you are having now.

Comment: @koropok i want to post array of dictionaries like [ [String : Any] ]

Comment: maybe you can try `[String : [String : Any]]`.

Comment: This may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/48537265/1042817

Comment: As @koropok suggested try doing something like this

["data": [
                 "EmployeeID": id,
                 "Longitude":  longitude,
                 "Latitude":   latitude,
                 "GeoTime":    dateString,
                 "UserToken":  "g98XQdy8B}rQ7?Q"
            ]
]